# How to parse a string which is formatted through Angularjs back to date object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A string is formatted like this:

```
 var str = $filter('date')(dateobject, myformat);
```

Now I want to parse str back to a javascript date object, when I parse str, assuming I know the 'myformat' which is used to format the string. But myformat is a variable, it changes from user to user.

Is there a way to do this in Angularjs?

Comment: Considering that your date format varies, maybe you can use Moment.js?

Comment: Thanks! But all the date time strings are formatted through Angularjs across the project we have now. In Angularjs, with the same 'format', like 'shortDate', the real result format is different if culture is different.

Comment: I think this filter is designed to be used in templates and there is no way to parse it back. Just preserve your date object in variable and you will not need to parse it.